# Why does pdf CustomPaint not render unless something else gets rendered?

Tags: flutter, pdf, pdf-generation

I don't know why rendering the CustomPaint only works when I render something else after it.

I use [flutter pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) and this is the code that should make it easier to reproduce:

```
static pw.Widget buildBarcode() {
  return pw.BarcodeWidget(
    color: PdfColor.fromHex("#000000"),
    barcode: pw.Barcode.qrCode(),
    data: "mailto:someone@somewhere",
    height: 80,
    width: 80);
}

static pw.Widget buildCustomPaint() {
  final paint = pw.CustomPaint(
    size: const PdfPoint(85 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 55 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
    painter: (PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
      canvas
        ..setStrokeColor(PdfColors.black)
        ..setFillColor(PdfColors.lightBlue)
        ..setColor(PdfColors.lightBlue)
        ..drawRRect(
            0, 0, 85 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 55 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 6, 6);
    });

  return paint;
}


class PdfGridApi {
  static Future<File> generate(List list) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();

    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) => [ 
        buildCustomPaint(),
        buildBarcode()
      ],
   ));
return PdfApi.saveDocument(name: 'my_contactcard.pdf', pdf: pdf);
}
```

If both get rendered everything works as expected but if I remove buildBarcode() nothing gets rendered anymore.

What am I missing in the CustomPaint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call either `canvas.strokePath()` or `canvas.fillPath()` to draw the contour of the previously defined rect shape.